# JPA mapping a Java Double to a SQL Number column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following SQL definition for a table which i can't change

```
CREATE TABLE network_model_property (
    id                NUMBER           NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name              VARCHAR2(100)    NOT NULL,
    ....        
    max               NUMBER(10),
    min               NUMBER(10),
    ....
)
```

The JPA'ed class definition is as following

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "network_model_property")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "PropertySeq", sequenceName = "MODEL_PROPERTY_SEQUENCE")
public class ModelProperty implements Serializable {

    static final long serialVersionUID = -3276944825572313129L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PropertySeq")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "max")
    private Double max;

    @Column(name = "min")
    private Double min;


    public Double getMax() {
        return max;
    }

    public void setMax(Double max) {
        this.max = max;
    }

    public Double getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    public void setMin(Double min) {
        this.min = min;
    }
```

I'm running a simple test case which throws this exception when 'hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate' is set

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: assure] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:677)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:132)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:224)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in POCOWN1.NETWORK_MODEL_PROPERTY for column max. Found: number, expected: double precision
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.validateColumns(Table.java:284)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1116)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1327)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:669)
    ... 38 more
```

And i've tried

```
@Column(name = "max", columnDefinition="Decimal(10,2) default '100.00'")
```

and

```
@Column(name = "max",precision=10, scale=2)
```

Comment: It maps the max and min property to wrong type.

Comment: Can you change the class? If so, change `max` and `min` to `Long` or `Integer`.

Comment: NO i need to keep column type as a float/double type.

Comment: There is no point in having Double in your Entity, while your Table does not support precision which the Double is about. As @John Farrelly suggests, set scale to 0.

Comment: And by the way, I think that any properties like precision, scale etc. set on @Column won't work, because you do not generate tables from entities, you simply MAP them to already existing table. So my guess would be to overlook your design. If you want to use doubles, work with them, but in the end map Integer to a real column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your table definition, the max and min columns have a precision specified, but no scale.  Try using scale = 0 on your Column JPA definition for the max & min properties.

Comment: I have my column datatype as `numeric` for the field Mobile Number in MySQL  and I set scale=0, it worked perfectly. My Code: `@Column(name="MOBILE_NUMBER", precision=0)
 private double mobileNumber;`. Thanks John

Answer (score 2):

It has been a very long time, but for the sake of completeness, the easiest fix, it to change your JPA Entity to defined min and max as `java.math.BigDecimal`.  The `java.math.BigInteger` and `java.math.BigDecimal` types provide direct conversion of SQL `Numeric` and `Number` data types.

Otherwise, to map the values correctly, you need to refer to the DB Driver for JDBC native type translation to determine what the jdbc types are translated to in java.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you do not specify the scale jpa converts it to the type numeric.So it is always better to specify the scale and the precision for the same.
So whenever you model the classes specify the scale and precision whatsever even if the scale is 0 specify it as 0.
Cheers mate!!

Answer (score 0):

In my cases, the data base worked well with my definition, only the validation failed. You could try to use "auto=none".

Answer (score 0):

**You need to especify the precision and scale and columnDefinition too as follow:**

```
@Column(name = "max", precision = 10, scale = 0, columnDefinition = "NUMBER (10)")

private double variation;
```