# Hibernate get data lach of column

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, entity, hibernate-mapping

I wrote a function get data from Db, it take most of the data but still lack some of column even i did define it in the entity.
Here is the result when i debug

[data is null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqcMA.png)

here is my entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BANK_FEE_AND_LIMIT")
@NamedQuery(name="BankFeeAndLimit.findAll", query="SELECT b FROM 
BankFeeAndLimit b")
public class BankFeeAndLimit implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private long id;

@Column(name="BANK_ID")
private Long bankId;

@Column(name="CASH_IN_FEE")
private Double cashInFee;

@Column(name="CASH_IN_FEE_AT_COUNTER")
private Double cashInFeeAtCounter;

@Column(name="CASH_IN_FEE_FROM_IB")
private Double cashInFeeFromIb;

@Column(name="CASH_IN_FEE_WITHOUT_LINK")
private Double cashInFeeWithoutLink;

@Column(name="CASH_OUT_FEE")
private Double cashOutFee;

@Column(name="CASH_OUT_FEE_WITHOUT_LINK")
private Double cashOutFeeWithoutLink;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="CREATE_DATE")
private Date createDate;

@Column(name="FEE_TYPE")
private Long feeType;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="LAST_UPDATE")
private Date lastUpdate;

@Column(name="MAX_CASH_IN_PER_DAY")
private Long maxCashInPerDay;

@Column(name="MAX_CASH_IN_PER_TRANS")
private Long maxCashInPerTrans;

@Column(name="MAX_CASH_OUT_PER_DAY")
private Long maxCashOutPerDay;

@Column(name="MAX_CASH_OUT_PER_TRANS")
private Long maxCashOutPerTrans;

@Column(name="MAX_NUMBER_CASH_IN")
private Long maxNumberCashIn;

@Column(name="MAX_NUMBER_CASH_OUT")
private Long maxNumberCashOut;

@Column(name="MIN_CASH_IN_FEE_AT_COUNTER")
private Long minCashInFeeAtCounter;

@Column(name="MIN_CASH_IN_FEE_FROM_IB")
private Long minCashInFeeFromIb;

@Column(name="MIN_CASH_IN_FEE_VALUE")
private Long minCashInFeeValue;

@Column(name="MIN_CASH_IN_FEE_WITHOUT_LINK")
private Long minCashInFeeWithoutLink;

@Column(name="MIN_CASH_IN_PER_TRANS")
private Long minCashInPerTrans;

@Column(name="MIN_CASH_OUT_FEE_VALUE")
private Long minCashOutFeeValue;

@Column(name="MIN_CASH_OUT_FEE_WITHOUT_LINK")
private Long minCashOutFeeWithoutLink;

@Column(name="MIN_CASH_OUT_PER_TRANS")
private Long minCashOutPerTrans;

@Column(name="STATUS")
private Long status;

@Column(name="WALLET_LEVEL")
private Long walletLevel;

@Column(name="WALLET_TYPE")
private Long walletType;

@Column(name="NUMBER_IBFT_FREE_BY_MONTH")
private Long numberIbftFreeByMonth;

@Column(name="NUMBER_CASH_OUT_FREE_BY_MONTH")
private Long numberCashOutFreeByMonth;

@Column(name="MAX_NUMBER_TRANSFER_IBFT")
private Long maxNumberTransferIbft;

@Column(name="MIN_IBFT_FEE_VALUE")
private Long minIbftFeeValue;

@Column(name="MIN_CASH_IN_FEE_FOR_PREPAID")
private Long minCashInFeeForPrepaid;

@Column(name="EXTRA_TRANSFER_IBFT_FEE")
private Long extraTransferIbftFee;

@Column(name="TRANSFER_IBFT_FEE")
private Long transferIbftFee;

@Column(name="CASH_IN_FEE_FOR_PREPAID")
private Long cashInFeeForPrepaid;

@Column(name="MIN_TRANSFER_IBFT_PER_TRANS")
private Long minTransferIbftPerTrans;

@Column(name="MAX_TRANSFER_IBFT_PER_TRANS")
private Long maxTransferIbftPerTrans;

@Column(name="MAX_CASH_IN_PREPAID_PER_TRANS")
private Long maxCashInPrepaidPerTrans;

@Column(name="MAX_TRANSFER_IBFT_PER_DAY")
private Long maxTransferIbftPerDay;

@Column(name="MAX_CASH_IN_PREPAID_PER_DAY")
private Long maxCashInPrepaidPerDay;

@Column(name="MAX_NUMBER_CASH_IN_PREPAID")
private Double test;

public Double getTest() {
    return test;
}

public void setTest(Double test) {
    this.test = test;
}
```

the null field is the test field which map to the MAX_NUMBER_CASH_IN_PREPAID column in the database.
Here is the data in database

[data in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AP4kG.png)

other field is still can fetch normally, only this field can't be get.

Comment: You might have a conversion problem between `Double test` and `the type of the column` in the DB.

Comment: Can you please share table schema. What datatype you have used in DB for "MAX_NUMBER_CASH_IN_PREPAID"

Comment: MAX_NUMBER_CASH_IN_PREPAID column has the data type of NUMBER, i'm using oracle

Comment: I think this is related to your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028028/jpa-mapping-a-java-double-to-a-sql-number-column .

Comment: Try @Column(name="MAX_NUMBER_CASH_IN_PREPAID", precision=0).. Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028028/jpa-mapping-a-java-double-to-a-sql-number-column

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to generate sitters and getters for the Columns you have then have a constructor to set the variables from within java classes or Controllers ( spring , servlet .. )

Answer (score 0):

Map be there is scale problem. Try

```
@Column(name="MAX_NUMBER_CASH_IN_PREPAID", precision=0)
private Double test;
```

Reference : [JPA mapping a Java Double to a SQL Number column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028028/jpa-mapping-a-java-double-to-a-sql-number-column)